# The Witches: A Discworld Board Game - Removing crisis counters

Tags: discworld-the-witches

When you solve a problem (easy or hard), and it has a crisis counter.... what happens with those chips? Are  simply removed from the game or they return to the initial stack?

For example, when there are only 2 players you play less crisis counters (8 or 10, I don't remember now). If these are just removed from the game, it will ran out soon (causing both players lose the game), but if they return to the stack there are more opportunities that does not happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crisis counter is returned to general stock (initial pool) and reused later on.

Rules under Success! (p.7):

> If there is a Crisis counter on the Problem tile then it is returned to the general stock.

Comment: Thanks! In the spanish translation I think isn't so clear.